# Deferred library for app engine goes to default version -- how to specify a target?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting `404` errors when I'm trying to use the deferred library because I'm running it within a module but it seems the deferred library is only going to the `default` module (aka my `app.yaml` module). How can I get the `deferred.defer` to run it within my specified module? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `name` and set a `target` for the queue:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue

Comment: Perfect -- thanks. Do you also know how to extract variable information from a `deferred.defer` run. Like, if I do this: deferred.defer(method,var), do you know how to extract `var` from the `POST` request?

Comment: It is explained here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push

You may want to use URL endpoints and the taskqueue.  That way, you tell it which queue to execute the task, and send post params as post data dictionary